# ActionBar won't remove

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just downloaded Android Studio and most of the activities have a blue Action Bar and Pink button with a envelope icon in it by default and I can't figure out how to remove it.

Things I've tried are:

1. Changing the app theme to xxxxx.Light/Dark.NoActionBar
2. Changed values in values>styles.xml

The most I can seem to do is make it gray but never removes it. Note I have changed nothing to the file yet.

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

values\styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

values\styles(v21)

```
<resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please see my answer below, it is in the file hosting the content_main, which you need to remove the AppBarLayout and Toolbar, as you can see this content_main.xml is wrapped in an include tag in that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main Layout file, you will see an `AppBarLayout` wrapping a `Toolbar` , if you don't want the `ActionBar`, this should be removed as these are the new widgets which replace what used to be known as the `ActionBar`

here is the activity_main.xml where you need to remove

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
     <!-- REMOVE THIS AppBarLayout to remove the Toolbar-->
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"         
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" 
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then in your Activity drop the lines:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the application tag in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: what is this comment trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will help you

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is removing the following lines from the main layout file that is created by default:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

If you need to prevent this from happening in the next projects you create, choose [Empty Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETXVI.png) instead of a Blank Activity